# Angular Reactive forms - Create input fields dynamically and get fill inputs with id

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

in Angular Reactive forms - i have array like this 3 items :

```
productList = [{
  productId : "104",
  productName : computer
},
{
  productId : "105",
  productName : sprots
},
{
  productId : "106",
  productName : location
}]
```

declared form group like this :

```
this.productFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      productFormArray: new FormArray([], CustomValidators.minNumberInputFieldRequired(1)),
    });
```

creating input fields like this :

```
productList.forEach((element) => {
        productFormArray.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(ValidationPatterns.required)]));
      });
```

bind like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formControls; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Question** :

how do i get 3 textbox **updated value** with **their id** on submit button?

Submit Button Event : -

```
if (this.productFormGroup.invalid) {
  return;
}
this.productFormGroup.value.productFormArray ? - it is return only update value, not Id.
```

there should be way to create text box with id while pushing item in form Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create productId and productName field(FormControl) in the FormGroup. On User Interface side only bind productName field as textbox, because productId is used for your internal reference. See the below code Example :
app.component.ts

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,FormArray } from '@angular/forms'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  productList = [{
    productId : "104",
    productName : "computer"
  },
  {
    productId : "105",
    productName : "sprots"
  },
  {
    productId : "106",
    productName : "location"
  }];

  constructor(public formBuilder:FormBuilder){

  }

productFormGroup :FormArray
  ngOnInit() {
        this.productFormGroup = this.formBuilder.array([])
        this.productList.forEach(product=>{
              this.productFormGroup.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                productId:[product.productId],
                productName:[product.productName]
              }))
        })
  }

  onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.productFormGroup.value)
    
  }
}
```

On User Interface side, bind the productName on textbox field. see the below code example:

```html
<div [formGroup]="product" *ngFor="let product of productFormGroup.controls">
    <input formControlName="productName" type="text" />
</div>
{{productFormGroup.value | json}}
```

I hope this will solve your problem. See the working code example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-example-2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: With this solution being implemented, for radio button change event, i need to reset the form. so I am doing this >
this.productFormGroup.reset();
with this, hidden productId also getting null, what could be other solution?

Comment: what you exactly want to achieve, so that I can help you. basically, reset function will clear the value from the formcontrol, if you are not passing the object. please share some more information...

Comment: This solution will not work when we saved data to db we're clearing our form ( this.form.reset()) - so second time we will not able to use it.
We would like to use productItem, where productname can bind with textbox  and on submit we should able to get for which productId we got productname value input box, by resetting, textbox value should be clear, but it should not clear productId, basically.